# Html and C# .net video player

Tags: jquery, video-embedding

I am working in a .NET project where I have to upload a video file in a folder using "fileupload". I do this successfully.

Now I required a video player which is showing these files. I used some jq video player like `mediaelementjs` and `jplayer` but 
they have some limitations. I have to give different format video for different browser but that is not my purpose.
I give only mp4 or flv file.
So is there any free jq player or any kind of .net supported player present? And how do I do this?

Comment: basically the video player is something you don't need to program. just use the html5 code shown in user1960725's answer linking to the single video file you have. Any modern browser should be able to display your files... if your users browsers are not compatible, have them install according browser plugins to support the video formats you offer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240">
  </object>
</video>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

Answer (score 4):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/).It is very simple to code and its support is good as well.Also available in free and paid version.It should help you in your case.It also give support for the FLV and mp4 for free as per your requirement